# Negating coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, calc

This actually seems like an easy thing to do but I have not found any solution:
I would like to negate/invert predefined coordinates as simple and with few characters as possible. I.e. using `(A)` as `(0,1)` as well as `-1*(A)` as `(0,-1)`.

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,1);
\coordinate (B) at (1,0);

\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw -(A) -- -(B); % This should read (0,-1) -- (-1,0)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `calc` library lets you do calculations on named coordinates with the syntax `($<calculation>$)`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,1);
\coordinate (B) at (1,0);

\draw [gray, densely dotted] (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
\draw [->] (A) -- (B);
\draw [thick, blue, ->] ($-1*(A)$) -- ($-1*(B)$); % This should read (0,-1) -- (-1,0)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I cant believe that I missed that. While trying several different solutions I forgot the outer parentheses around the math term. Thank you!